# HTML - Change progress bar color

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

So I have a progressbar that looks something like this:

```css
.progress {
  border: none;
}

.red,
 ::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: red;
}

.blue,
 ::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: blue;
}

.orange,
 ::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: orange;
}

.green,
 ::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>The progress element</h1>
<label class="progress">Downloading progress:</label><br>
<progress class="red" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="blue" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="orange" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="green" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress>
```

Somehow the colors wont change. I have added them all as classes, but cant figure this out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress#see_also).

Comment: `,` separates two selectors. That’s not what you want here. Use a different combinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`.red, ::-webkit-progress-value`
to
 `.red::-webkit-progress-value`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
progress {
 border: none;
 background: grey;
}

progress {
 color: lightblue;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: lightblue;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: lightcolor;
}

.red::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: red;
}
.blue::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: blue;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
 background: grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The progress element</h1>

<label for="file">Team 1:</label>
<progress id="file" class="red" value="53" max="100"> 32% </progress>
<br><br>
<label for="file">Team 2:</label>
<progress id="file" class="blue" value="21" max="100"> 32% </progress>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The preferred method going forward for modern browsers is [`accent-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color).

```css
.progress {
  border: none;
}

.red {
  accent-color: red;
}

.blue {
  accent-color: blue;
}

.orange {
  accent-color: #C07B00;
}

.green {
  accent-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>The progress element</h1>
<label class="progress">Downloading progress:</label><br>
<progress class="red" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="blue" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="orange" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress><br>
<progress class="green" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress>
```

It seems that Chrome has already dropped support for its `-webkit-progress` psuedo-selectors, and Firefox's implementation is buggy and likely to be dropped as well. `accent-color` is supported by Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and is currently the only method with [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#widget-accent), although they're still in drafting.

> **Note:** Chrome (and by extension, Edge) currently automatically switches the background color from white to dark grey, depending on
> how bright the accent color is.

Answer (score 0):

### Add formatting:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The progress element</h1>
<style>
    progress {
  border: none;
  background: crimson;
}

 

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: rgb(2, 18, 24);
}
 
</style>
<label for="file">Team 1:</label>
<progress id="file" value="53" max="100"> 32% </progress>
<br><br>
<label for="file">Team 2:</label>
<progress id="file" value="21" max="100"> 32% </progress>

</body>
</html>
```