# Styling HTML Progress Bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have a progress bar I want to style. I have figured out how to change the colour of the background of the progress bar but I can't change the value.

**Here is my CSS:**

```
progress {
    height: 2rem !important;
}
progress[value] {
  --color: red !important; /* the progress color */
  --background: #8499E0; /* the background color */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: var(--background) !important;
    height: 2rem !important;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: var(--color) !important;
}
progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: var(--color) !important;
}
```

I have changed the variable --color to red which I believe should change the progress bar to red, yet it displays a darker blue colour:

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6JSi.png)

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/).

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried changing colour and following the tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)!

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no problem with your CSS, maybe the issue resides within your html file. You can also try the answer provided in this link [HTML - Change progress bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121101/html-change-progress-bar-color).
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I ultimately feared! It's a WordPress website template and I'm adding custom CSS to style it so do you think it's styled somewhere in the template? If that is the case though, shouldn't CSS !important override any styling? Cheers

Comment: I am not experienced with WordPress but if even the inline style have !important, it cannot be overridden, though that might be a rare case.

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing wrong. Your browser is probably loading cache data, just clear cache and reload.

If you're using a PC (which i believe you are), you can do that by switching to developer tools, click and hold on the reload tab on your browser, and click on "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

OR

USE A DIFFERENT BROWSER.

Comment: I cleared my cache and used Microsoft Edge and that didn't change anything!

Comment: can i see your html code?

Comment: I saw in a different comment where you were wondering if wordpress was responsible, I think you can check that in developer tools (the style section).

Comment: I saw in a different comment where you were wondering if wordpress was responsible, I think you can check that in developer tools (the style section).

Comment: Wow, I looked in the developer tools > style section and a variable --color-content-primary is what decides the colour of the progress value. Since it is styled by that variable, why can't I just directly give the progress value element its own colour with !important to override that variable?

Answer (score -2):

Then try entering the style tag yo the name of your value.If it doesn't come please let me know

Comment: This seems more like a comment than a definitive answer.